# Gtk toolbar looking strange

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, toolbar

I use [c program with gtk gui](https://gitorious.org/maximus/book/source/f7c24d730ec49d5ce0b661278273f39dce9818a7:code/gui). It works, but on some computer it has a good toolbar : [image: big buttons with text] but on the other bad toolbar ( small buttons without text) : [image]

Some check :

```
dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'
```

output :

```
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64    3.8.6-0ubuntu3.1     amd64 GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-bin 3.8.6-0ubuntu3.1  amd64 programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface         library
ii  libgtk-3-common 3.8.6-0ubuntu3.1 all common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk-3-dev 3.8.6-0ubuntu3.1  amd64        development files for the GTK+ library
ii  libgtk2-perl 2:1.247-2 amd64  Perl interface to the 2.x series of the Gimp Toolkit library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64 2.24.20-1ubuntu1 amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-bin 2.24.20-1ubuntu1 amd64 programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-common 2.24.20-1ubuntu1 all common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-dev 2.24.20-1ubuntu1    amd64        development files for the GTK+ library
```

What is the reason ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

[Claude](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/) have found the solution :

gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(tbar), GTK_TOOLBAR_TEXT);

Now it works.